# Cassandra: What happens when an entire datacenter goes down?

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have a Cassandra cluster with 3 datacenters of 6 nodes each - DC1, DC2 and DC3 [like this](https://academy.datastax.com/sites/default/files/multi-data-center.png). Lets say I have a `NetworkTopologyStrategy` and while creating a keyspace I do,

CREATE KEYSPACE test WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1' : 3 ,'DC2' : 3,'DC3' : 3 }

which makes sure that any write is replicated on 3 nodes in each datacenter only after which the write is successful.

**What happens if an entire datacenter goes down ?**

Lets say all nodes in Dc3 goes down! In this case, a write request to update a table, even with Write consistency level of ONE (*Consistency Level: A write must be written to the commit log and memtable of at least one replica node.* I would assume it needs to be written to atleast one node in each datacenter.) would fail right ? This request will try to update atleast 3 nodes in DC3, which it cant because of all nodes being down.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeReplication_c.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing with CONSISTENCY LEVEL of ONE your writes will not fail.

**Explanation:**

Your keyspace specifies 3 replicas in each datacenter which ensures that there will be 9 copies of each row of your data.
When you write at CONSISTENCY LEVEL of ONE the co-ordinator will give success once the data is written to memtable and commitlog of a single node (only a single node, not one node per datacenter).

So what happens about replicas? The data is stored as hinted hintoff (default 3 hours) which gets replicated once nodes are up (in your case data center 3 is up). If the nodes are not up before 3 hours then it will try to repair the data using [builtin repair mechanism](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dmlAboutDataConsistency.html?scroll=dmlAboutDataConsistency__ul_l1m_rks_gk) .

> which makes sure that any write is replicated on 3 nodes in each
>   datacenter only after which the write is successful

Your this statement does not stand true if you are writing with CONSISTENCY LEVEL ONE.

For more details on 
[Multiple Datacenter Write](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/architectureClientRequestsMultiDCWrites_c.html).

> Three replicas in each data center: This configuration tolerates
>   either the failure of a one node per replication group at a strong
>   consistency level of LOCAL_QUORUM or multiple node failures per data
>   center using consistency level ONE.